# How can I store objects other than strings in a wxPython ComboBox?

Tags: python, combobox, wxpython

I have a list of Vertex objects, each with their own labels and id's.  How can I use this list as a model for a wxPython ComboBox such that when a user selects an option, I can immediately retrieve the Vertex id?

It appears that ComboBox only accepts strings as a model. I cannot create a dictionary of label to id pairs since there are duplicate labels.

I noticed a ComboCtrl class which I can subclass to create a specialized combo box, but I feel like there is a easier solution to this.

Comment: How about `labels + id`?

Comment: That would work.  I could create a dictionary that maps labels + id to id's, or extract the last part of the string and convert it to an id. Still, I wonder if there is any easy way to just store objects.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This topic came up on the wxPython IRC channel earlier today, but in regards to the ListBox. Fortunately, both the widgets inherit from wx.ItemContainer, so you can do the following:

```
for item in ObjList:
    self.myCboBox.append(item.label, item)
```

Then in the event handler, you'd do something like:

```
itemObject = self.myCboBox.GetClientData(self.myCboBox.GetSelection())
itemID = itemObject.id
```

That should work.

Comment: So how would you set the selection for the wx.ComboBox given the itemObject.id?

Comment: You could do something like myCboBox.GetItems() and then look for your label and do myCboBox.SetValue(mylabel), but this seems like a hack. It also won't work that well with posters problem of having duplicate labels.

Comment: Since you have the item object, you don't need to look up the label. You'd just use something like mycomboBox.SetValue(itemObject.label)

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward approach would be storing vertexes in a list and retrieve selected value by index (returned by wx.ComboBox `GetSelection()`).

**Edit:** q&d example:

```
l = [{"value" : value_1, "label" : "label"},
     {"value" : value_2, "label" : "label"}]

def on_select (event):
    i = event.GetSelection()
    print (l[i]["value"])

# ui construction omitted    

Bind (wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, on_slect)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing, but I'd rather display the vertex label instead of the id.

Comment: @bgoosman: added example snippet; the idea is to use "label" keys for ui but retrieve value upon selection (list of dictionaries was chosen arbitrary, it could be list of tuples or list of lists instead).

Comment: Ok, so the idea is that we use the rank of each vertex in the array to create a one-to-one mapping between label and id?

Comment: @bgoosman: the idea is to map combo item and "vertex object" list index (you could pack id's into record structure as well, if there is need for it); to make things more clear: what is the structure of your "vertex objects with labels and id's"?